# How to find all the empty sites?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, reports, storage

I am using SharePoint 2013 on-premises. There are so many empty sites. Is there a PowerShell way to identify these sites?

I need a list of these sites so they can be deleted. I searched all over Google and Bing but no luck yet.

Comment: How do you define "empty"?

Comment: Site have no contents (remember I am not talking about the system list or libraries like site assets, etc.)